# Convert cell array of cells into cell array of strings in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab, string, cell

Using regexp with tokens on cell array of strings I've got cell array of cells. Here is simplified example:

```
S = {'string 1';'string 2';'string 3'};
res = regexp(S,'(\d)','tokens')
res = 

    {1x1 cell}
    {1x1 cell}
    {1x1 cell}
res{2}{1}
ans = 
    '2'
```

I know I have only one match per cell string in S. How I can convert this output into cell arrays of strings in a vectorized form?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is even worse than you thought. Your output from [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/regexpi.html) is actually a cell array of cell arrays *of cell arrays* of strings! Yeah, three levels! The following uses [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) to get rid of the top two levels, leaving just a cell array of strings:

```
cellArrayOfStrings = cellfun(@(c) c{1},res);
```

However, you can also change your call to [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/regexpi.html) to get rid of one level, and then use [VERTCAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/vertcat.html):

```
res = regexp(S,'(\d)','tokens','once');  %# Added the 'once' option
cellArrayOfStrings = vertcat(res{:});
```

Comment: @gnovice: You are right about those levels. I think the second solution is better for the speed and clearness. Thanks again.

Comment: @gnovice: I don't know how often I have read the documentation of regexp - yet I haven't noticed the 'once' option. Thanks!