# Matlab regexp tokens - optional tokens and size of the returned array

Tags: regex, matlab, token

Say we have a collection of files with names which can be either `myfilename_ABC` (type 1) or `myfilename_ABC=XYZ`(type 2). Providing that at any one time we supply `regexp` with an array of filenames of only one of these two types, how do I get it to return an array with either 1 (for type 1) or 2 (for type 2) columns containing the 3-letter combinations? I have tried using

`'myfilename_(\w+)=?(\w+)?'`

but this returns a cell array with 2 columns even for type 1 filenames where the second column contains empty string `''`.

Comment: The number of groups is set in the pattern, you can only use some post-processing to get rid of the unwanted columns.

Comment: You can [split](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btqcpjk-4) with `'myfilename_|='` and ignore the first (empty) result.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this if you simply create match expressions for each case and use a [conditional operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#bqv21pe-1). For example:

```
>> type1 = {'myfilename_ABC'; 'myfilename_DEF'};
>> type2 = {'myfilename_ABC=XYZ'; 'myfilename_DEF=UVW'};
>> matchExpr = 'myfilename_(\w+)=(\w+)|myfilename_(\w+)';
>> results1 = regexp(type1, matchExpr, 'tokens', 'once')

results1 =

  2×1 cell array

    {1×1 cell}  % Each cell contains 1-by-1 results
    {1×1 cell}

>> results2 = regexp(type2, matchExpr, 'tokens', 'once')

results2 =

  2×1 cell array

    {1×2 cell}  % Each cell contains 1-by-2 results
    {1×2 cell}
```

Notice that I placed the longer match expression (`myfilename_(\w+)=(\w+)`) *before* the shorter one (`myfilename_(\w+)`) so that it would attempt to match the longer first. I also used the [`'once'` option](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#inputarg_option) (to match the expression only once per input) to [remove an extra layer of cell encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2624744/52738).